# Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation

Tags: sql, t-sql

i'm getting error when i used this

```
,CONCAT('£', CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CAST(CAST(SUM((CL.CONTRACTLEN)/12 * 
S.sale * profit)/100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS MONEY), 1)
 AS VARCHAR)) "Total Lost Value"
```

error

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 6
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Comment: The SUM() aggregation had some null-values as input. (Excluded from the SUM result, of course.)

Comment: why are you casting as decimal, then as money, then converting it to varchar and then casting to varchar again?

Comment: @Lamak for this £11,155.02

Comment: @jarlh so how can i get rid from this error

Comment: the comment from @jarlh explains just the "warning" you are getting, not the error (and the warning isn't important in this case)

Comment: so how can i get rid this warning as im new in this

Comment: @Skorpion you don't want to get rid of warnings, they are not errors and they where here just to remember you. In this case one of the two columns got null values and those nulls are being ignorated. Since any math operation with null will result in null, if they are not ignorated by the `SUM` you can get null as the result so the engine is just being nice to you

Comment: Note that the default length of [`VarChar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql) is one character. Always specify a length.

Answer (score 0):

Start with something simple.

```
SUM(CL.CONTRACTLEN)
```

Then build it up until you get the error and fix the error.

What is the data type of CL.CONTRACTLEN?

You are getting an error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int".  You have some implicit integer conversion going on.

You need to learn how to approach and solve a problem.